# Not able to login into session (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having issues trying to login into my Rails app. I attempt to login and it redirects my back to my login page. I checked what password I was providing and it's on point. It does not give me an error at all in the browser. I checked my console and I get a 200 code which means its found the page.

Here are my controller actions/routes

```
 get 'login',  to: 'sessions#new', as: 'login'
 post 'login', to: 'sessions#create'
```

Here is my Sessions Controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end
    
    
   def create
        user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
        if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
        #    log_in user
           sessions[:user_id] = user.id
           redirect_to user_path(user), notice: 'Logged in!'
        else
           flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
           render :new
        end
    end


    def destroy
        session.delete(:user_id)
        redirect_to '/', notice: 'Logged out!'
    end
    
end
```

and here is my login form.

```
<h1>Login</h1>
<%= form_tag '/login' do %>   
<div>   
    <%= label_tag :username %><br>   
    <%= text_field_tag :username %>   
</div>   
<div>   
    <%= label_tag :password %><br>   
    <%= password_field_tag :password %>   
</div>   
<div>   
    <%= submit_tag "Log In" %>   
</div>   
<% end %>
```

Is any one able to spot why its redirecting back to my login page?

Comment: What is redirect_back_or? Where is that defined? I do not believe it is a standard part of rails.

Comment: @KaomTe its a helper method in my sessions_helper file. I was having this issue even before that, but I changed to the standard just in case.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the structure of the controller. Can you please also include the code for ```User#authenticate```? Or are you using [```has_secure_password```](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html)?

Comment: I am using has_secure_password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your example has

`sessions[:user_id] = user.id`

shouldn't it be

`session[:user_id] = user.id`

`session` should be singular

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you. I've been staring at it for hours and overlooked that.